# popup-menu requires RN 0.55+ error in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-popup-menu

I am using the library "react-native-popup-menu.

```
npm install react-native-popup-menu@0.14.0
```

version:0.14.0(it's latest)

when I try to run then error showed: **this version of popup-menu requires RN 0.55+ 
but the problem was I install the latest library then why to get an error?**

*NOTE:   added a library in Package.Json file.*

Comment: whats your rn version?

Comment: @MelihMucuk rn version doesn't know but how to check rn version? and thx for the response.

Comment: you can find in package.json.

Comment: rn version did not find in package.Json

Comment: are you sure on working a react-native project? In the root folder, there is package.json file.

Comment: rn version 0.54.0 rn means react native version i didn't know so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180794/discussion-between-rushi-dave-and-melih-mucuk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install `0.9` version of `react-native-popup-menu`. Last version is not compatible with your react-native version.

You should install it on your root folder like below:

`npm install --save react-native-popup-menu@0.9`

more info: https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu#react-native-compatibility

Comment: just note - `0.12` should be okey as well.